# How to find the concavity of $\sin(x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In an exam candidates are asked to draw the sketch of the graph of $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$. Its increasing and decreasing behviour can be found easily but to find its concavity I found its second derivative but I am unable to figure out the roots of its second derivative which are necessary to find its point of inflexion.

Please help in this.

Comment: What is the second derivative that you found?

Comment: The problem of finding such roots reduces to solving the system $$y\tan y=1/2$$ and $$y=x^2.$$ So the problem reduces to seeing what curve the first equation represents.

Comment: @kingW3 The second derivative is $2[\cos(x^2)-2x^2\sin(x^2)]$.

Comment: @Allawonder You simply paraphrased the problem.

Comment: @prashantsharma Obviously. But in a form that may be more amenable to analysis, or at least yield some insight of you were appreciative at all.